# How do i get permission to view and download user photos

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, permissions, facebook-c#-sdk, user-permissions

We have built a functional standalone C# touchscreen printer kiosk desktop app that allows users (currently just me) to view, download and print thier own facebook photos. Our company would like to get this part of the app in production immediately. How do I get permission for various users to view, and download selected photos. Is it possible to show an allow screen and pull back an access token that allows permission, and add that token to the requests?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking: How do I create a facebook application and use the c# sdk.

Yes it is possible to do everything you ask for, more than that, it's exactly how you described it: you have a fb application, you ask users to allow the application (along with the needed permissions) and then you get an access token which you then add to all api requests.

Please read the documentation and follow the tutorials and when you have a specific question come back and ask it.

Links:

- [Canvas Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)
- [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
- [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
- [facebook-csharp-sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/)